# Plaid Link Development Issue: Redirect URI Not Working, Pop-up Opens at OAuth Bank

Tags: plaid

While setting up the Reinitializing Link in development, I am not being sent to the redirect uri page.
When I go through the flow the widget opens, but when I get to an oauth bank, clicking continue opens a pop up. This is not what I hoped would happen based on this Plaid video - https://youtu.be/E0GwNBFVGik?si=Bxd_uCSgcXK9DThy&t=1166.

I am sending the redirect_uri to plaid and getting a link token.
I am storing the link token in localstorage.
I use the link token when making the request to Plaid.
I have added the redirect uri to Plaid as an Allowed URI.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pinned comment from Plaid on the linked video that addresses this:

Important update! At 19:38, you might notice your test application is still using the pop-up flow, even if you supply the redirect URI. This is because in September 2022, we changed the OAuth flow so that Sandbox now works exactly the same as Production; meaning that it will either go with the pop-up flow or the redirect flow depending on the platform it's running on. In March 2023, we also changed the default behavior on mobile, so that it will always use the pop-up flow.

To get the redirect flow, you can use your browser's developer tools to emulate a webview useragent. For example, On Chrome, for example, select the "Toggle Device Toolbar" option from within Chrome's Developer Tools and create a new virtual device configuration with a WebView user agent. You can use the following user agent string:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 5 Build/LMY48B; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/43.0.2357.65 Mobile Safari/537.36`

Also, this means the information at 26:30 regarding the Sandbox environment is no longer correct. Sandbox now works the same as Production.